# On conditional Independence for three random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Assuming $X,Y,Z$ are random variables on a finite space, such that

1. $X,Y$ are independent
2. $X,Y$ are conditionally independent  given $Z$
3. $Z$ is a binary variable

Is it true that $X,Z$ are independent or $Y,Z$ are independent ?
Thank you for your help

Comment: $Y$ is conditionally independent of $Y$ given $Z$ !  Are you sure?

Comment: I've just corrected it , $X$ and $Y$ are conditionally independent given $Z$. Thanks for noticing